# Android - Login/Registration with PHP, MySQL - Register Button not Doing Anything

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, registration

So while I'm pretty experienced with Java, I'm pretty new to Android development. I've been working on an app that will require users to make an account before using it - so I need a login / register button. I've coded it up following TonikamiTV's YouTube tutorials (with slightly different parameters and a different XML layout), yet when I go to click the register button, nothing happens. No error message on the screen, nothing in my logcat, just nothing. I've tried using my own username and password along with the base username root and blank password WAMP provides. I have tried both 127.0.0.1, localhost, and 10.0.2.2 in different combinations, all with no success. Any ideas on why would be awesome.

RegisterActivity:

```
package example.com.musicapptest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    final Button registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    final Button toLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            final String clickName = name.getText().toString();
            final String clickEmail = email.getText().toString();
            final String clickPassword = password.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response){
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(clickName, clickEmail, clickPassword, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Register Request:

```
package example.com.musicapptest;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Carter Klein on 6/26/2016.
 */
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest{

private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/android_login_api/register.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name", name);
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams(){
    return params;
}
}
```

activity_register (XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/bg_register"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
        android:hint="@string/hint_name"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:textColor="@color/input_register"
        android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
        android:hint="@string/hint_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/input_register"
        android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/input_register"
        android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

    <!-- Login Button -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="#ea4c88"
        android:text="@string/btn_register"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLinkToLoginScreen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/btn_link_to_login"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

register.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1:8080", "root", "", "android_layout_api");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users (name, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $name, $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: since when does mysql run on port 8080? that's weird. plus your db code simply assumes success. you have absoluteyl no error handling, and blindly report "success", no matter what actually happened. if that port number is wrong, you don't even connect to the db and EVERYTHING ELSE you do with the db will also fail. yet, wow... success in spite of 100% failure.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords as plain-text.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention I am running my localhost on port 8080, not port 80. And would you be able to elaborate at all on why it's always assuming success? And even if so, if it always assumes success, wouldn't that mean it would always add a user? In this case, literally nothing is happening, when I go to phpmyadmin and go to the table of users I created, nothing shows up. Also, thank you for such a quick response!

Comment: Didn't see the rest of these comments - I will look into this. Thank you! Last question is (and this is going to sound dumb), how do I test just the php?

Comment: You can test with the PHP with a web browser. And you can write the request string to your logcat and see if you're sending it correctly. Or you can write something into the logcat during the button onclick to make sure it works.

Comment: As a follow-up question: suppose I was enable to put some kind of password encryption system into this code I'm working with now. Is there any way, as of now, you can see this code working? I am still having the persisting problem of the register button doing absolutely nothing :/